# Unable to have a report in BC Compare using command line

Tags: command-prompt, beyondcompare

I need to create a batcha file to execute several comparioson between several folders. I'm trying to use Beyond Compare but I'm unable to get a report using the command line.
I use this script:

folder-report layout:side-by-side &

options:display-mismatches &

output-to:%3 %1 %2

this script is saved on my desktop as "My Script.txt"
then I use this command on prompt

BCompare.exe @"My Script.txt" "My File.txt" "Your File.txt" "My Report.txt".

Where is my error?

p.s. Otherwise cna you suggest me another tool?

Comment: It appears this error: "a fatal error has occurred: Unable to save report: Cannot create a file "". The syntax of the name of the file, in the directory or in the volume, it is non correct. The script will now exit"

Answer (score 2):

To automate a Beyond Compare folder compare report, use the following script:

```
criteria rules-based
load "%1" "%2"
expand all
folder-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:"%3"
```

To run the script, use the command line:
    bcompare.exe @c:\script.txt "c:\folder 1" "c:\folder 2" "c:\report.txt"

The @ character tells Beyond Compare to run a file as a script rather than load it for interactive comparison.

See the [Scripting Reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripting_reference.html) topic in Beyond Compare's help file for a full list of scripting commands.

To generate a report that includes file contents:

```
criteria rules-based
load "%1" "%2"
expand all
select diff.files
file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:"%3"
```

Comment: Thank you but now I have a different problem....the report compares only the structure of the folders but it doesn't report if two files having the same name are different...

Comment: The default comparison criteria compare modified timestamp and size. To compare the contents of files similar to double clicking to view contents interactively, add the line "criteria rules-based" before the load command in your script.

Comment: Thank you. I solved using the "diff" command line in Kdiff3, adding the recursie property :)

Comment: To include the content of files in the report instead of just listing if they are different, use the "file-report" command.

Comment: DO you mean: I should cop the program you wrote above, loading the two folders, but I should use "file-report" instead of "folder-report"? So the last line would be something like <<file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismathes output-to:"%3">>?

Comment: I edited my original reply to include an example with the "file-report" command.